# Do I need to implement terminal emulation if I have a ptty?

Tags: terminal-emulator, pty

If I have a pseudo terminal given to me (from say a pty-req (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4254.txt)) do I need to emulate the data coming back, or is that already emulated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the level of emulation you're talking about. The pty uses the remote server's terminal driver, so options controlled by `stty` (and the analogous system calls) will be emulated there.

But you're running an application that sends terminal control escape sequences, you'll need to handle that locally.